# I am trying to insert data into db from Django view file. No error but data is not saving into db

Tags: python, django

I am trying to insert data into DB from a Django view file. No error but data is not saving into DB.
I am trying scrape data from flipkart page, it is not showing any error but data is not saving into db

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as ureq
from testapp.models import Redmi_Mobiles
import requests

def scrape_view(request):
    session=requests.Session()
    my_url="https://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/pr?sid=tyy%2C4io&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DRealme&otracker=nmenu_sub_Electronics_0_Realme&sort=price_asc" #link which I want t scrape
    uclient=session.get(my_url,verify=False).content
    page_soup=soup(uclient,"html.parser")
    containers=page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"_3O0U0u"})
    for container in containers:
        product_name=container.div.img["alt"]
        price_container=container.findAll("div",{"class":"_1vC4OE _2rQ-NK"})
        price=(price_container[0].text)
        rating_container=container.findAll("div",{"class":"hGSR34"})
        rating=rating_container[0].text

        new_redmi=Redmi_Mobiles()
        new_redmi.model_name=product_name
        new_redmi.price=price
        new_redmi.rating=rating
        new_redmi.save()

    return redirect('home')
#models.py
class Redmi_Mobiles(models.Model):
    model_name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    rating=models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.model_name
```

Comment: Try to debug your `scrape_view` method. Maybe parser don't work correctly, and `containers` is empty.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try debugging your code _step-by-step_. There is nothing wrong with the saving part of your code; there should be an issue with your data. If you are using a decent IDE, try debugging with that; otherwise use `print` statements to confirm your have the data you expect to have.

Comment: I tried debugging it ..it gives an error "Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'testapp'"

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` empty file into your testapp directory?

Comment: yes, it is present